# Discord.py: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Tags: python, database, sqlite, discord.py

I am trying to make a warn command for my discord bot that inputs the following 4 values into a database, member ID, server ID, reason, and warn ID. The warn ID is the result of the last fetch into the table plus 1. However, when I try to add to the warn ID, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 47, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1325, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

Here is my code:

```py
  @commands.group()
  @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles = True)
  @commands.bot_has_permissions(manage_roles = True)
  async def warn(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = 'No reason provided'):

    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is not None:
        return

    db = sqlite3.connect('warns.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f'SELECT warn_id FROM warns WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} AND member_id = {member.id}')
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    if result is None:
      sql = ('INSERT INTO warns(guild_id, member_id, reason, warn_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?)')
      val = (ctx.guild.id, member.id, reason, 1)
    elif result is not None:
      sql = ('INSERT INTO warns(guild_id, member_id, reason, warn_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?)')
      val = (ctx.guild.id, member.id, reason, result + 1) # FAILS HERE

    await ctx.send(f'{check_mark} **{member.name}** has been warned.')

    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
```

I've tried converting the result to an integer but that didn't work. I don't know why this is happening now.

Comment: Did you try printing out `result` on the line before it fails to see if it's what you expected?

Comment: It printed `('1',)`. How can I turn this just into a number so that I can add an integer to it?

Comment: `cursor.fetchone()` gives always tuple even if database returns single value so you have to get `result = result[0]` or better after checking `if result is not None` use it  `val = (..., result[0] + 1)`

Comment: Looks like you need to access the value from the tuple by indexing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
int(result[0]) + 1
```

Your printout indicates that `result` is `('1',)`, that's a `tuple` of length 1 containing a string. The `[0]` gets the first element out of the tuple, and the `int()` converts the string to a number, so you can add a number to it.

You can also use `+` on strings or on tuples in Python, but both operands have to be the same type. (It concatenates them.) That's why the error messages were complaining about the operands rather than the `+` operator.

Comment: @Dom: furas makes a good point that the result isn't guaranteed to be length 1 as that depends on your data. If it's length zero, the index `[0]` will crash, and if it's longer than 1, the remaining results would be silently ignored.

Comment: Okay @gilch. I'll see if I can find an alternative/workaround, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

`cursor.fetchone()` gives always tuple (similar to list) even if database returns single value so you have to get first element from tuple

```
 result = result[0]
```

Better do it after checking if `result` is not `None

```
if result is not None:
     val = (..., int(result[0]) + 1)
```

As @gilch noticed it needs also `int()` to convert string `'1'` to integer `1`

Comment: Upon doing this I get `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Comment: result has string `'1'` which you have to convert to integer `1` using `int()`